# Family Members Birthday Dates all different, but our birthdays will fall on same day, even Leap Years. There is a total of 9 in this Birthday Club. .

Tags: puzzle, constants, birthday

I can compile a list if needed and post, but I noticed this over 50 years ago, My Father, My Brother and Myself our Birthdays fall on the same day of the week every year. Even Leap years, that does not change this.

**Years ago before computers**, I went to the Local Library, did research and Found the **"Roman Calendar" was the most accurate to use**. I compiled on Paper via Pencil **a Calendar based on the "Roman" principle**, I made a template and as I said, Our birthdays fall on the "same day" every year. All three of us. How can this be.

**Now we have found that 6 other family members** have this on our Birthdays being the same day. This makes a total of 9 of us.

**This all has to do with a number of "7" as a constant**. I am no Mathematician by no means.

Can someone who knows their stuff respond. I mean I am 65 and the days have always been the same refering to a same weekday for our birthdays every year.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that I don't see how your question has anything to do with "ordinary-differential-equations". Also, regarding "prime-numbers", although $7$ is a prime number, the particular aspect that's apparently pertinent to your question is that it's the number of days in a week in the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), and I believe also the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), which is what I assume you mean by "Roman calendar" as this calendar was the one that was predominantly used in the Roman empire.

Comment: As for calanders, yes we can agree on the ones you posted. As for my question have I placed it in the wrong thread on the forum?

Comment: Do you mean that birthdays fall on the same day _of the week_? If so, this only means they are apart by a multiple of $7$ days. Say, Jan 1st and Jan 15th are always on the same day of the week, no mystery here! (The fact that leap years don't affect that means that the birthdays are probably either all before March 1st or, more likely, all after March 1st).

Comment: You are correct on after March 1, but I just can't figure how this could have happened, and 2 are adopted.. just seems ironic.

Comment: Thank You. All birthdays fall between 3/1 and 12/31

Comment: If you pick 8 random people, it's very unlikely for them all to have this birthday relationship with you, but within a group of ~80 people (e.g. your extended family), it's not unlikely to find 8 of them that do.

Comment: Did you know that in 2023,  the dates 4/4, 6/6, 8/8, 10/10, and 12/12 all fall on Tuesday. So too do  7/11 and 11/7, and also 5/9 and 9/5, as well as the final day of February, and you can say all this with *dd/mm* and *mm/dd* calendars.  These dates coincide like this every year.  [Spooky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule)

Answer (score 1):

If all the birthdays in question are in months after February, then the *difference* between any two of the birthdays is the same number of days every year, even in leap years. If this difference is a multiple of 7, then the birthdays fall on the same day of the week.

A related mathematical topic is [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Converting between dates and days-of-the-week is closely related to working with integers mod 7.

Comment: I will look calculator up in morning Karl. Thank you for the link.